# Why does my entry.get() function in tkinter not work?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I've only started Tkinter with python (on Ubuntu, if that's relevant), and I'm following a tutorial. It's covering the entry widget, and in one section, it's talking about the get() module for the entry widget. I've tried to make this code on my own (there's also a label widget) and I'm not sure how to use it. I type into the code 'name = entry.get()' and on the next line, 'print(name)', but when I type something in the entry widget, it isn't displayed on the terminal.

Here is the code in question:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# Label
label = tk.Label(
    text="Hello, Tkinter",`
    fg="white", # Set the text color to white`
    bg="black", # Set the background color to black`
    width=11,`
    height=10`
)
label.pack()

# Button
button = tk.Button(
    text="Click me!",`
    width=25,`
    height=5,`
    bg="blue",`
    fg="yellow",`
)
button.pack()

# Entry
label = tk.Label(text="Name")
entry = tk.Entry()

name = entry.get()
print(name)

label.pack()
entry.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I tried inputting the entry.get() command straight into the terminal but that still doesn't work.
Please help.

Comment: Your code never calls `entry.get()`. My guess is that you're calling it before the user has had a chance to enter anything in the widget.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the text of your entry? Could you please add this relevant part of code?

Comment: This code does not call `entry.get()`.  It's very confusing when you tell us "I tried calling entry.get()" but it is not actually in the code.  Please show us **the actual code** that you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a get_value function to get entry input, I added that function to click me button. So when u click the button you'll get entry input. I hope it can be helpful.

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_value(): #This part for getting entry.
    name = entry.get()
    print(name)

window = tk.Tk()

# Label
label = tk.Label(
    text="Hello, Tkinter",
    fg="white", # Set the text color to white,
    bg="black", # Set the background color to black,
    width=11,
    height=10
)
label.pack()

# Button
button = tk.Button(
    text="Click me!",
    width=25,
    height=5,
    bg="blue",
    fg="yellow",
    command=get_value # function added here
)
button.pack()

# Entry
label = tk.Label(text="Name")
entry = tk.Entry()

label.pack()
entry.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could add that get_value function to the entry widget or something similar?

Comment: You'll get blank output. Because u calling entry.get() in UI setup you will get what u have at the beginning in entry. All functions are running in mainloop. That's mean u don't get input from the entry at the beginning. So, once you start typing ur function won't work anymore. Because, your functions already started in mainloop().

Comment: How do you add the function to the main loop?

Comment: like what I did. I added function into button. So, when I clicked I get entry values

Comment: anytime if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Just to clarify would I add entry.get() to the entry widget or get_value?

Comment: you should only add in get_value, so once you click button it'll print what u have in entry. You can copy paste my code, and take look how it is work.

Comment: strange im getting an error saying that get_value is not defined

Comment: did u forget to define get_value(). Code is working I just tried again